# Android Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I just started Android development with ionic framework on Linux (Ubuntu).

I successfully created my ionic project using the command:

```
sudo ionic start demo blank
```

Now to add the android platform to the project, I ran the command:

```
sudo ionic platform add android
```

And this is the result it gave me:

> function bold() { [native code] } https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-default-resources/archive/master.zip
>   [=============================]  100%  0.0s
>   Adding android project...
>
> Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
>
> Path: platforms/android
>
> Package: com.ionicframework.demo504884
>
> Name: demo
>
> Activity: MainActivity
>
> Android target: android-24
>
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>
> Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
>
> ls: no such file or directory: /home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/res/mipmap-*
>
> Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android
>
> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
>
> at /home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:222:19
>       at _fulfilled (/home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
>       at /home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:857:14
>       at runSingle (/home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (/home/awa/Desktop/mobile/demo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>
> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

At first I doubted if it had successfully added the android platform so I ran the same command again (`sudo platform add android`) and it said platform already existed.

Now seeing the last section of the error, I set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable by putting this code at the end of my `.bashrc` file located my home directory.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/awa/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/home/awa/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/awa/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

I saved the file. In order to build my project, I ran the command:

```
sudo ionic build android
```

and it gave the error:

> add to body class: platform-android
>
> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

I verified again to make sure I had succeeded in setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable correctly. So in the Command line I ran the command `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and it gave as output:

```
/home/awa/Android/Sdk
```

...which is the right directory for my SDK.

I have tried other solutions like setting the environment variables in the `.profile` file but nothing changed.

Now I am suspecting the problem may have something to do with my sdk version though I'm not entirely sure.

What am I doing wrong, or what I'm I missing?

Comment: You need to restart the shell in order to have the environment variables loaded

Comment: I did that. I even restarted but it didn't work still

Comment: Try setting it manually? `export ANDROID_HOME /path`, then run your command

Comment: I tried that now (for the second time) and it still gave the same error.

Comment: I think you need the path containing the android command. Notice in the error it says something like android: command not found, or it isn't in your PATH

Comment: Make sure that you are adding correct directory to your path and not a link location. Also, try typing "android" and press return to confirm that android is in your PATH.

Comment: when I type android on the command line, it brings up the android sdk manager